# Troubleshooting 500 Server Error Zend Framework application

Tags: zend-framework

I am facing a 500 Server Error and I see that many people here have had this problem and it can be too broad so I would like to ask my question differently.

I have confirmed with my host that the server is fine and if I replace content of index.php in public_html it shows everything is working.  The problem seems to be in my script/environment and I am trying to track it down.  My question is which are the common paths to check?

I have confirmed that its going through application.ini fine, the front controller plugin is fine (I have 1), the routing is working fine but it doesnt get as far as the IndexController which I am testing with.

I have tried to wrap $application->bootstrap()->run(); in a try-catch but this didnt help.  Any help with how to troubleshoot such an issue appreciated.  I am trying to track through what the application is doing to find where it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem.  Turns out I had an infinite loop in my application in one model.  I traced through the dispatch process until I narrowed down to the line that was causing trouble and removed it.  Was helpful to me in walking through what the application does step by step and ticking off everything.